# Java Desktop app and Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, desktop

Is it possible for a Java desktop application to interact with Java Servlets or Java EE Applications?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is definitely possible, take a look at [Web Services](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/index.html). Here is another [link](http://gdp.globus.org/gt4-tutorial/multiplehtml/ch01s02.html) with a simpler explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EJBs (stateful or stateless). Installing an EJB client on your desktop app will take care of most of the communication details for you. And you always have the option of communicating via pure RMI. Both options would typically be more efficient than a SOAP or REST based solution. Good options if you don't need to worry about creating a non-java version of your desktop app.